# Chrome crashes on Acer Iconia A200

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser, crashes, chrome-for-android

I'm seeing problems identical to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115803), where Chrome either crashes, becomes unresponsive, or the screen goes black if I switch between tabs.  Logcat shows:

> OpenGLRenderer is out of memory

According to the Chromium issue, this stems from bugs in the Tegra video drivers.  For the Asus Transformer, it was fixed by a system update.  (I'm running the most recent ICS update on my Iconia Tab.)

Is there anything I can do to get Chrome working reliably on the A200, and is there any hope of Acer fixing their software?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Acer? I'd see if you can find a reproducable way to make it happen with the built-in apps, then report it to Acer as a bug. Might not get anywhere, but you won't know till you try.

Comment: I'm on an A200 as well; I'm not having that crash. I'm getting other crashes, tho', with Chrome. The recent build is better than the older one.